# Can I re-sign an .apk with a different certificate than what it came with?

Tags: android, signing, apk

If I have an apk can I remove the current signing and some how re-sign it with a different .keystore file and still have the application install?

**Update**: I managed to get it to work with Jorgesys' solution and where I messed up before was that I unzipped the .apk then rezipped it after removing the META-INF folder and changed the file extension back into .apk. What I should have done is simply opened it with winzip and delete the folder inside of winzip.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

try this

> #### 1) Change the extension of your .apk to .zip
>
> #### 2) Open and remove the folder META-INF
>
> #### 3) Change the extension to .apk
>
> #### 4) Use the jarsigner and zipalign with your new keystore.

hope it helps

Comment: I gave that a go, but when I try to install the app it throws a parse exception.

Comment: hi Anton post your stacktrace

Comment: i posted the result in my question

Comment: Sounds like you deleted `AndroidManifest.xml` from the root of the APK file, rather than only the `META-INF`.

Comment: hehe =) java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Nope I didn't. I did exactly those 4 steps.

Comment: Well I don't really have experience with what you're doing, but the /data directory has permissions 770, so you can't even list the contents of the /data directory.

Comment: if you want a quick solution just check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16146126/700869

Comment: This is what does vendor script [sign_target_files_apks](https://github.com/android/platform_build/blob/master/tools/releasetools/sign_target_files_apks) (well, it works with zip archive of target files).

Comment: 1-3 steps is just = zip -d foo.apk META-INF/\*

Comment: @Elenasys thanks for your solotion . its work 
But i have a problem : I want change manifest from apk file and use itself meta-info folder , i need to re-sign an .apk with a different apk certificate , for example sign my app with facebook certification . is it possible ?

Comment: This will not work with apks signed with the new v2 signing schema https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2.html

Comment: How the heck do you do number 3

Comment: **NOTE:** This *wont't* work with [APK signing schema v2](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2) (~2017)

Answer (score 33):

If you are looking for a quick simple solution, you can use **Google's `apksigner` command line** tool which is available in revision 24.0.3 and higher.

> ```
> apksigner sign --ks release.jks application.apk
> ```

You can find more information about apksigner tool, at the developer Android site.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html

Or, alternatively, you may use an open-source apk-resigner script

Open Source apk-resigner script https://github.com/onbiron/apk-resigner

All you have to do is, download the script and just type:

> ```
>    ./signapk.sh application.apk keystore key-pass alias
> ```

Comment: The signapk.sh script to download is no longer available.

Comment: @dac2009 thanks for the comment, I have updated the link.

Comment: fyi Google's new apksigner has the capability to resign out of the box https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html

Answer (score 13):

Note if you use [v2 signing schema](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2.html) (which you will automatically if you use build-tools 24.0.3+ in AS) you cannot just remove the META-INF folder from the APK since v2 adds its signing data to a zip meta block.

Google's [new apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html) introduced in build-tools 24.03 (Android 7) is however able to resign APKs. You can just repeat the signing command to sign with a new keystore/cert (the old ones will be removed).

```
apksigner sign --ks keystore.jks signed_app.apk
```

---

*Shameless plug: if you want a easier tool that can sign multiple apks and has better log output use: https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer (uses Google's apksigner.jar in the background)*

Answer (score 10):

```
zip -d my_application.apk META-INF/\*
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk
```

Answer (score 7):

Signing for release: $1.apk -> $1_release.apk"
GeneralMills&GoogleApps#2012
Step 1: Removing any previous signing
Change the extension of your .apk to .zip
Open and delete the folder META-INF
Change the extension to .apk
    Or 
Command: 
•   zip [originalapk]
Example:
•   zip "$1".apk -d

Step 2: Signing with release.keystore..
Command:
•   jarsigner –verbose –keystore [keystorefile] –signedjar [unalignedapk] [originalapk] alias_name
Example:
•   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin> jarsigner -verbose -keystore release.keystore -signedjar "$1"_unaligned.apk "$1".apk release

Step 3: Aligning
Command:
•   zipalign -f 4 [unalignedapk] [releaseapk]
Example:
•   C:\Users\G535940\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\too
ls>zipalign -f 4 "$1"_unaligned.apk "$1"_release.apk

Step 4: Cleaning up
Command:
•   rm 4 [unalignedapk]
Example:
•   rm "$1"_unaligned.apk

Additional Commands might help:

1. To generate new key with keytool
   keytool -genkey -alias  -keystore
2. To list keys 
   keytool -list -keystore

Command to generate a keyhash for the Facebook features

Command:
•   keytool -exportcert -alias alias_name -keystore [keystorefile] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Example:
•   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias release -keyst
ore release.keystore |opens l sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Note:
To sign our apks we have downgraded JDK from 1.7 to 1.6.0_43 update.

Reason:
As of JDK 7, the default signing algorithim has changed, requiring you to specify the signature and digest algorithims (-sigalg and -digestalg) when you sign an APK.

Command:
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore [keystorefile]
[originalapk] alias_name

Answer (score 3):

All the solutions above work. Just a note why it didn't work for you when you re-zipped:

Some of the files inside the .apk need to remain stored (compression at 0%). This is because Android will use memory mapping (mmap) to read the contents without unpacking into memory. Such files are .ogg and some of the icons.

Comment: Just experienced this ... if you rezip APK completely, it will lead to inexplicably weird behavior. APK can be installed, APP may/may not start up, but will freeze eventually when it hits mmap code that is zipped.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your keys are stored in `keys.keystore`, you can run:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore keys.keystore
Your keystore contains 1 entry

your_key_alias, Jan 3, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 8C:C3:6A:DC:7E:B6:12:F1:4C:D5:EE:F1:AE:17:FB:90:89:73:50:53
```

to determine the alias of your key. Then run:

```
zip -d your_app.apk "META-INF/*"
jarsigner -verbose -keystore keys.keystore \
   -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -sigfile CERT \
   your_app.apk your_key_alias
```

to re-sign `your_app.apk` with the key named `your_key_alias`.

The extra `-sigfile CERT` option seems to be necessary as of JDK 8.