# sign apk separately (either eclipse or command line) - (not directly from eclipse project)

Tags: android

I am doing my android projects in eclipse . I can easily sign the apps with my keystore using eclipse. But, if I export the unsigned APK(not project, just apk)  and keystore to another computer, can he be able to sign it either using eclipse or command line .  I tried using command line :

```
   $ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

But I'm getting some zip size errors like this:

```
 jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 7395 but got 7498 bytes)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5089042/1321873

Answer (score 1):

[jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 463 but got 465 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5089042/1321873) worked for me :

This is what you should do

Rename the .apk file to .zip
Unpack the .zip file and remove the META-INF folder
Zip the folder again and rename it to .apk
Sign the apk: