# Failure [install_parse_failed_no_certificates] when attempting to install APK to the emulator

Tags: android, cmd, emulation, apk

I downloaded Myfiles.apk from the internet and I'm trying to install it to my Android emulator.

While installing Myfiles.apk file through the command prompt, I'm getting this error.

I tried following in command prompt

```
C:\android-sdk\tools> adb -s emulator-5554 install C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFiles.apk
```

How do I install this APK to the emulator correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is INSTALL\_PARSE\_FAILED\_NO\_CERTIFICATES error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error)

Answer (score 45):

This [site](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-solution-install-parse-failed.html) 
 helped me a lot to properly sign the unsigned apk. But,for the last process i.e. for `jarsigner`,following command need to be used

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore    my_application.apk alias_name.
```

Further do look upon this [`unable to sign zipexception`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8992819/739306) if you encounter with any `zipexception` error . So overall,use following procedure

1. `keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000`
2. `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore    yourapkalign.apk alias_name`
3. `zipalign -v 4 yourapk.apk yourapkalign.apk`

Now,you can successfully install the apk file.

Comment: `zipalign -v apkfile` is not sufficient, 
you need to execute `zipalign -v 4 apkfile`
you need to provide align size.

Comment: Also, I have been told that you need to run zipalign last, or jarsigner breaks the alignment.

Comment: I am trying to install app to my phone. I've executed all the above commands. (Though I think the second one should be `... -keystore debug.keystore ...`. But I am getting the following error:
>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl840513344.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/MYKEY.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl840513344.tmp/base.apk is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?]

Comment: 2021 and also getting this same error as @LRDPRDX . Any solution?

Comment: For Android 11 (No signature found in package of version 2 or newer): zipalign first, then instead of jarsign:
`apksigner sign --ks ~/.android/debug.keystore --ks-key-alias someKey foo.apk`

Answer (score 11):

It means that the apk you downloaded hasn't been signed with any certificate, debug or otherwise.

You can sign it from the command line, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `androiddebugkey` the sign the apk.

The keystore lives in `~/.android`, named `debug.keystore`.

Run

`keytool  -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`

To see the debug key, we can see its name is `androiddebugkey`

Run the following command to sign the apk.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore yourapp-release.apk androiddebugkey
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you should use `apksigner` and not `jarsigner`. `jarsigner` is "not recommended" [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/zipalign).

In my case `jarsigner` was not signing it properly, and using `apksigner` solved the problem.