# Android Studio 2.2.2 fails to install apk to device/emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I've got:

> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
>
> Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly.
> If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration is >specified in the Gradle build script.
> Error while Installing APK.

Trying to run android project in Android Studio v2.2.2 on MacOS.

After that whatever I tried didn't help at all.

I tried to completely uninstall studio and re-install it again, tried to clean and rebuild the project, tried to configure signingConfigs. Nothing helped.

So, I'm still unable to run the app neither on a device, nor on emulator. I tried to generate signed release build and then install it to the device. Again I've got a system alarm saying about problems while installation.

Has anyone faced that? Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failure \[install\_parse\_failed\_no\_certificates\] when attempting to install APK to the emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636396/failure-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-when-attempting-to-install-apk-to)

Comment: No, that wasn't a reason, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

To everyone who have got similar problem. Ensure you don't have any files without extension in your project. I've added some custom fonts to assets. And one of those fonts had a file (named smth like *Icon*, no extension). After I deleted that file, everything went Ok.