# Issue in installing apk file in rooted device ( INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES )

Tags: android, debugging, adb, penetration-testing

I am trying to perform VAPT of an Android application to do so I am trying to install an apk file on Android version 9.0 (API 28) hosted on Genymotion, but I am getting error
Error-

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads] └─$ adb install application.apk 
Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to install app-uat.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl2111374642.tmp/base.apk using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify]
```

V1 and V3 signatures are missing also V2 signature is present.

I found another solution but its not working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636396/failure-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-when-attempting-to-install-apk-to) and [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error) I also tried on other version of android like 8.0, 8.1 and 7.1 but either the android system is crashing or I am not able to make andorid connection in those device I am getting adb error like adb cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037 i tried its solution also by killing the server and setting its port to 5555 but it is also not working its again running at port 5037 and not getting connected to android device

Comment: The APK file you are trying to install has simply a defect signature.

Comment: but its verifying using the apksigner command, please explain a bit more about this.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the verbose output of apksigner verifying the mentioned APK.