# Export unsigned apk from a Gradle Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, artifacts

I usually create projects with Eclipse and import them into Android Studio, because I hate the project structure AS gives me. In it´s module settings, I have the possibility to create artifacts which allow me to output the built apk to a certain path.

[image]

Now I have created a Gradle project directly with AS and it seems that those projects have quite less options than eclipse projects. I don´t find anything to output my apk and I don´t find any apk inside my project folder after building.

[image]

How do I get my unsigned apk out of the build process??

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use

```
Build > Make Project
```

to build an apk file from Android Studio.

You can get your unsigned apk under the below path

```
$YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/apk
```

unsigned apk files will have "unsigned" text in their names.

**[ UPDATE ] :**

In Recent release of Android Studio you will not get apk file on sysncing or Make Project. There are two other methods in order to get the apk file

1. Run the app
2. Execute assemble Task from Gradle panel present in right hand side of Studio window or from embedded terminal window on bottom(in project Root)

gradlew assembleDebug(or whatever build varient you want a build for)

and the update new apk path will be

```
$YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/outputs/apk
```

This has been done by Android Tools team to improve the Android Studio performance.

Comment: `Make Project` no longer seems to build an apk as of Android Studio 0.8.

Comment: Not as of Android Studio 0.8, It was removed in 0.5.4 or 0.5.3. Now Make project only compiles the code and create R.java (if required) nothe the gradle tasks. So i order to create apk file you have to run the respective gradle task like assembleDebug from command line or by double clicking on the right listed task in right hand panel.

Comment: I will update the answer after confirming the version soon, Right now in office busy with some work enjoy.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/artifacts.html  what is the point of using artifacts?   I thought it was to generate an unsigned apk debug apk, etc but it seems as if you can simply go to the build/apk folder to get the unsigned apk so long as you run assemblerelease from gradle menu or build via command line (at least in intellij IDE?).  I just  configured an artifact but I'm having trouble figuring out what to truly do with it.  Can someone please help clarify the difference and use and/or point me in the right direction?  many thanks

Comment: I don't see this in 1.0.2. I do see an -unaligned.apk

Comment: I have updated my answer, thanks for getting my notice on this.

Comment: Be aware: Android Studio hides the output folder in the project view, but it exists! Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/25131515/813951

Comment: Your outdated answer still works with the latest android studio.

Comment: There is no $YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/apk directory, (AS 2.2 Preview 5) and using assembleDebug creates a debug signed apk which is not an unsigned apk, build/outputs/apk is debug signed

Comment: @behelit Please check the Update section in recent releases it is moved to $YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/outputs/apk .

Answer (score 25):

The above answer of pyus13 did not work for me (Android Studio 0.8.1).

Instead use

```
Run > Run "YourProject"
```

to build the code and create the unsigned apk. You can find your apk file under

```
$YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/outputs/apk
```

**UPDATE**

Still works with Android Studio 1.5.1 
You only get new APKs when you have code changes since you last built your code.

Comment: @Wayfarer What exactly did not work for you? Which version of Android Studio are you running? Why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: `apk` found after `run/run` in the mentioned directory `/build/outputs/apk` - confirmed in version "Android Studio 1.0 RC 4" - nevertheless I found 2 apks: `app-debug.apk` and `app-debug-unaligned.apk` - don't know the diff between them :D

Comment: Can't edit my own comment. Just use `app-debug.apk` and discard the `app-debug-unaligned.apk` version as that is only an intermediate step to build the aligned one.

Comment: When I try to sign app-debug.apk I get "jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size"

Comment: @TomKincaid This has probably nothing to do with the topic discussed here. A simple Google search brings you to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089042/

Comment: The output folder only had debug signed apk for me.  This post is how I got a truly unsigned apk:  http://entzeroth.com/export-unsigned-android-apk/

Comment: @BeritLarsen Yes, it does (see update above). Just tested it myself with version 1.5.1 Please try it again.

Answer (score 19):

Open Gradle panel, open the tasks list of your project and double click on BUILD task, then under " -> build -> outputs -> apk" you will find your unsigned APK with name  -release-unsigned.apk

Comment: This is the correct answer with the latest version of Android Studio. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me - never would have found that!

Comment: Except that the folder is now hidden (v1.0.2). Problem described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25131515/813951

Answer (score 3):

As of Android Studio 1.5 you can now generate an APK using

```
Build > Build APK
```

Which you can then find under

$YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/outputs/apk.

Edit:
New Android Studio gives this Path:

```
$YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/outputs/apk.
```

Comment: Just used the feature in 1.5.1: The path is $YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/outputs/apk.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to build an apk by using the command line (Android Terminal).

1. Choose the Terminal in Android Studio - very bottom next to Android Monitor and Version Control
2. Build apk with command
   Windows: gradlew.bat assembleRelease
   Mac: ./gradlew assembleRelease
3. Find unsigned apk file - /app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk

Tested in Android 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Edit app.gradle **buildTypes** block, set

```
signingConfig null
```

Then rebuild.