# How to show hidden files in Android Studio

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I'm a new Android Studio user (I used eclipse before).
I'm trying to follow the official [Build Your Project With Gradle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html) tutorial.
In the "Build the project from the command line" section it is mentioned that the apk file location is in `app/build/apk/` but when trying to navigate to this specific path with Android Studio, it seems that it is missing... I looked for the same path using the command line and **it do exist**, so apparently Android Studio is hiding this folder (and maybe others as well). I tried to find explanation how to make Android Studio show the hidden files/folders, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything. I also tried searching same problem in Intellij IDEA, because I know Android Studio is based on it, but it seems that the menus are a bit different...

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: In Android Studio: There is an option in the gear icon in the explorer. Enable the option for Show Excluded Files. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68153399/8094969

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your project in studio 0.8.2 the sighned apk files are generated at

```
yourprojectfolder\build\outputs\apk
```

Android-studio is not hiding the file, it is developed so as to show the generated files folder only.It won't show you either the oututs folder.You can verify this by moving your .apk file to say resource(res) folder and you will be able to see that.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to make Android Studio show the outputs folder as well?

Comment: Yaniv, there is no way currently.It is similar to the way, when we try to use windows "open file dialog" to open say .pdf files in a folder which contains various files with various extensions, but the open dialog will show us,just the available pdf files in that folder. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

To show the output folder in Android Studio, just rename it to `output` by going to the place where you saved your files. Then you will see your output folder in Android Studio.