# Re-sign an Android Apk

Tags: android, android-emulator, certificate, apk

How can I Re-sign an android apk. I referred to this answer [Can I re-sign an .apk with a different certificate than what it came with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-resign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with)

but got stuck with Android Manifest.xml missing error.

Comment: at which step? also, are you sure the manifest is still in the apk?

Comment: Sounds like you deleted AndroidManifest.xml from the root of the APK file, rather than only the META-INF . Just like the original question says.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I resign an .apk with a different certificate than what it came with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-resign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with)

Comment: Detailed Flow:  1.converted apk to zip form. 2.Removed all files from META-INF ,remaining files(lib,res,AndroidManifest,classes.dex,resources.arsc) 3.zipped the file back to .apk   4.Used jarsigner to sign the apk (output adding: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
adding: META-INF/ANDDEV_K.SF.......) 5.Tried Installing the apk on the emulator then I got (Android manifest.xml is missing in the apk)

Comment: You can also try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15786087/700869

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I re-sign an .apk with a different certificate than what it came with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-re-sign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with)

Answer (score 27):

Friends I found a work around to this .                                                             Resign Android Apk using android default debug.keystore.

1. **Open the apk in the winzip browser and not by unzipping to a folder.
2. Delete  `META-INF` folder .zipping again is not required.**
3. `Jarsigner -verbose -keystore debug.keystore yourapk.apk aliasname`

   ```
   **Example** `-Jarsigner –verbose –keystore debug.keystore androiddebugkey.`
   ```
4. `jarsigner -verify yourapk.apk`
5. `zipalign -v 4 yourapk.apk  signedapk.apk`

**Step 1 and 2** was where I was doing wrong which gave me androidmanifest xml missing error.

Comment: After the step 3 I get a message "jar verified." and
Warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.

How do I overcome this warning???

Comment: jarsinger argues on self-signed certificates. You can avoid this warning if you use certificate received from Verisign, GoDaddy or any other CA.

Comment: The default password for alias androiddebugkey is "android"

Comment: You should be using the zipalign tool

Answer (score 5):

Downgrading to JDK 1.6.0_43 solved the problem.

To sign apks using JDK 1.7 one has to use these keywords "-sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1"

Reason:
As of JDK 7, the default signing algorithim has changed, requiring you to specify the signature and digest algorithims (-sigalg and -digestalg) when you sign an APK.

Command:
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore [keystorefile]
[originalapk] alias_name

Comment: why downgrade when you can just use `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore [keystorefile] [originalapk] alias_name`?

Comment: FYI md5 was completely phased out by Oracle and is no longer supported https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jre-will-no-longer-trust-md5-signed-code-by-default