# Resign apk with different keystore

Tags: android, apk, sign

Currently I'm getting the apk signed with the private keystore file but I want to sign that apk with different keystore file. How can I resign that apk..?

Comment: no dude i don't think so

Comment: please explain ..1- are you want to sign the same signed apk or new apk of same project......

Comment: I want to resign the same apk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I re-sign an .apk with a different certificate than what it came with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-re-sign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you should check below SO thread

[Can I resign an .apk with a different certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-resign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with)

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119839/re-sign-an-android-apk) one also may help you

Comment: what would be the path for this command..Jarsigner -verbose -keystore debug.keystore yourapk.apk aliasname

Answer (score 37):

You can resign your apk with different keystore.

Follow these steps:

Signing for release: `$1.apk -> $1_release.apk"`

**Step 1:** Removing any previous signing

- Change the extension of your `.apk` to `.zip`.
- Open and delete the folder META-INF
- Change the extension to `.apk` 
  Or
  Command: `zip [originalapk]`
  Example: `zip "$1".apk -d`

---

**Step 2:** Signing with release.keystore:

Command:

```
jarsigner –verbose –keystore [keystorefile] –signedjar [unalignedapk] [originalapk] alias_name
```

Example:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin> jarsigner -verbose -keystore release.keystore -signedjar "$1"_unaligned.apk "$1".apk release
```

---

**Step 3:** Aligning

Command: `zipalign -f 4 [unalignedapk] [releaseapk]`

Example:

```
C:\Users\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\too ls>zipalign -f 4 "$1"_unaligned.apk "$1"_release.apk
```

---

**Step 4:** Cleaning up

Command: `rm 4 [unalignedapk]` 
Example: `rm "$1"_unaligned.apk`

---

**Additional Commands might help:**

1. To generate new key with keytool

```
keytool -genkey -alias  -keystore
```

1. To list keys

```
keytool -list -keystore
```

---

**Note:**

To sign our apks we have downgraded JDK from 1.7 to 1.6.0_43 update.

Reason:

As of JDK 7, the default signing algorithim has changed, requiring you to specify the signature and digest algorithims (-sigalg and -digestalg) when you sign an APK.

Command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore [keystorefile] [originalapk] alias_name
```

Comment: I needed `zipalign -p -f 4`, specifically (note the extra `-p`)

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the open-source apk-resigner script, which is very easy to use.

APK-resigner: https://github.com/onbiron/apk-resigner

```
./signapk.sh calculator.apk ~/.android/debug.keystore android androiddebugkey
```

Also if you want to sign the APK with your debug key, you may use.

```
./signapk.sh calculator.apk
```

Answer (score 7):

1. remove old sign

   > zip -d xxxx.apk(your apk file) META-INF/*
2. sign apk

   > jarsigner -verbose -keystore xxxx.keystore(your keystore) -signedjar out_sign.apk(outfile) unsign.apk(unsign apk) xxxxxalias(your alias)
3. if sign apk not work and jdk >= 1.7

   > add params **-digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA**
   >   jarsigner -verbose **-digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA** -keystore xxxx.keystore(your keystore) -signedjar out_sign.apk(outfile) unsign.apk(unsign apk) xxxxxalias(your alias)