# In Livecode, how would one go about including Android launcher icon sizes besides the hdpi 72x?

Tags: android, livecode

After compiling an app with a 72x icon, The scaling on several devices of differing dpi makes the icon appear slightly blurry. I have icons of different sizes (xhdpi 96x, mdpi 48x, and ldpi 36x) but have not yet found out how to include them or found confirmation if it is possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the standanlone builder in LiveCode doesn't support this. I've added it as a feature request in the quality control center.

Comment: I can confirm that this has been added to our roadmap. We'll hopefully get this added during the LiveCode 6.0 release cycle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete guess but there's currently no hooks for messing with the apk in the middle of the build so you will probably need to unzip it and place your icons in the correct folders drawable-hdpi etc then re-zip and [resign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119839/re-sign-an-android-apk)