# Re-signing apk-file (Adobe AIR). How to get old key?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, google-play, apk

I have apk-game based on Flash (Adobe AIR). It was published on Google Play.
Some days ago I updated my AIR SDK from version 3 to 14 and re-compiled my apk.
After this, where i try upload new apk, I get error from Google:

*Upload failed 
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your 
previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are 
signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s): 
[ SHA1: EE:68:CF:C6:FF:40:CB:B9:65:8C:E6:89:C2:FB:A6:52:81:33:59:7F ] 
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have 
fingerprint(s): 
[ SHA1: B4:89:02:73:3D:82:96:4F:57:00:13:0C:D8:1C:64:8D:B0:D1:D0:7A ]*

So, I must re-sign new apk with old key.
I found utility named Jarsigner. It can re-sign apk, but I must have file *.keystore to do it.
I can't find info, how to get *.keystore from my old apk (because new apk must have the same signature). Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Keystore File Lost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850686/android-keystore-file-lost)

Comment: you should check below SO thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-re-sign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119839/re-sign-an-android-apk

Comment: I've seen these topics, but it does not say how to get a new keystore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore