# Re-signing apps already signed

Tags: android, apk, code-signing

Are there any solutions for re-signing apps that are already compiled? For example, if the app is already signed by an outside vendor with their own key, can we resign the app with our company's own specific key without recompiling? Specifically, is there a utility we can use? Apple has a way of doing this, but it is very difficult and time consuming. Is there an easier solution to this, perhaps through an app available on Google Play or the Android Store?

Comment: No way, it can't be done.

Comment: Yes, it can be done, however I'm not sure your outside vendor would appreciate your tampering with their code/signature. It's probably better to ask them for an unsigned version.

Comment: It can be done, and has been asked before. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-resign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with

Comment: Is there an update on the answer? or it is simple cann't be done ?

Answer (score 4):

No, that would enable stealing an app in a too easy way.