# Android shows signature conflict error while installing app

Tags: android, installation, signature

I want to provide an updated version to my app,

It is downloaded from my site  not from google play service.
When I download the updated version its not replacing the old version, instead it shows error"An existing package by the same name with conflicting signature".

Is there any solution to replace the app without manually un-installing the older version from the device.

Comment: do you have written any code for updating the exiting apk if new version is available?

Answer (score 1):

Every android application file – apk has two main things:

1. package name – (unique id of app like com.example.application)
2. signature

More information about the second. Every apk file should be signed with developer keystore. If this is the debug version it could be debug-keystore.
In this keystore there are some information about developer and other information.

When you install application android system at first checks package name – whether or not this application have been installed already. And if so system checks signatures. The signature of installed app and app to be installed must be the same. Otherwise you will get error, you describe in your question.

So, the answer is: not, you can't install another application with the same package name if the signatures of installed and to be installed apps are different.
You must uninstall previous version and install new version, if you need new version.

Comment: is there any way to find the older version signature and use it in the updated version.

Comment: If you find .keystore with which old apk was signed, then you can resign this apk. See for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-resign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error message already describes your issue. Your issue is that your app is not signed with the same signature as the previous version.

So to prevent this error message you must sign the app with the same signature as the previous version.

More details about application signing can be found in the [Android Developers documents](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: Yes, I agree. Make sure the keystore that you used to run your app is same as the keystore in upgraded version.

Comment: In both version i have used only the default keystore but sysytem used for development differs and i have not signed the older version.

Comment: I don't get it what you mean with default keystore, but anyway: When your previous app hasn't been signed, updates are not possible since the system can't ensure that the new update is developed by the same entity. This is the reason, why you should **always** sign your apps.

Comment: is there any way to delete the older version automatically using the package name during the installation of latest version.

Comment: No, there is no way. And if you find a way to do what you want, you may have found a serious vulnerability of Android.

Answer (score 0):

If That is Developed By You or a Developer.

Once Check weather the Entire Code and Package Names are Same or not, in the `Manifest` file..

If Its Not that app is not from you or your known developer means.

You need to Uninstall Previous Version and Install New One,

That Error You are Getting Is that App is Not Signed, means When we are Using UnSigned App It cannot Replace at the part of Signed app. first of all make your app as Signed.

Check more at [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

How to Make a App as self-Signed at [here](http://lessons.runrev.com/s/3527/m/4069/l/32674-how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-an-android-app)

Answer (score -2):

to protect the identity of the application each revision(update) requires the same signed key(SHA1) which was used for the earlier  release. 
Eclipse by default uses debug-key to sign in all the packages.

Use the same method by which you first installed your app and everything should just work.

Comment: I don't agree with this! The app must be signed with the same key, but the signature doesn't need to be equal.

Comment: what is the difference between signature and key ?

Comment: The signature of the app is the hash sum of application package signed with your private key.