# sign-> zipalign -> sign -> zipalign? same error happens repeatedly

Tags: android, google-play

I made apk by apportable and try to upload apk to android market.

At first when I uploaded the apk says

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files. You need to create a valid signed APK. Learn more about signing.
```

That's OK. I should sign the apk, so I signed and uploaded

```
jarsigner -keystore android.keystore -verbose myApk.apk myalias
```

then market shows this error.

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.
```

That's OK too. I must zipalign the apk.

```
zipalign -f 4 myApk.apk myAlignedApk.apk
```

now I uploaded again, but the first error(missing signing) happens again!!

I think I should do signing -> zipaligning

This procedure is correct.

How can I fix or solve this problem?

---

Thanks to you

I could investigate the problem deeply.

There is something wrong with signing not zipaligning

sign normally or with -digestalg SHA1

```
$ jarsigner -keystore android.keystore -verbose myApk.apk myAlias
```

or

```
$ jarsigner -keystore android.keystore -digestalg SHA1 -verbose myApk.apk myAlias
```

it shows the error

```
$ jarsigner -verify animalparade-release.apk

jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for assets/se_maoudamashii_magical24.caf
```

However, sign like this ,

```
$ jarsigner -keystore android.keystore -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -verbose myApk.apk myAlias
```

the market shows the error like

```
Upload failed

Your APK has been signed with multiple certificates. Please only sign it with one certificate and upload it again.

Upload another APK
```

Comment: android.keystore is use for debug not for publish apk so sign your apk using your custom keystore.

Comment: android.keystore is made by myself. I have release another apk with this keystore via eclipse.

Comment: @whitebear Have you made two different certificate for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I re-sign an .apk with a different certificate than what it came with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-re-sign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitebear try to update your SDK build tools from ask manager to version 20 or latest and create signed apk again and try.

Hope it works.

Comment: SOmoehow I updated the SDK and it works. I am not sure the reason though, the problem is sloved

Answer (score 1):

Recently I updated to Android Studio 2.2 and started facing this issue.
Solution:
Delete generated signed APK and try generating again. Error Gone!

Answer (score 0):

jarsigner -keystore KeystoreName -storepass KeystorePasword -keypass KeystorePassword ExportedUnsignedApkName.apk KeystoreAlias

**Example :**

jarsigner -keystore MyCustomKeystore -storepass 123456 -keypass 123456 MyUnsign.apk mycustomkeystore

./zipalign  -v 4  Unsignapkname.apk  Signedapkname.apk

**Example :**

./zipalign  -v 4  MyUnsign.apk  MySign.apk

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#AutoReleaseMode

To specify your keystore and alias, open the project ant.properties<> file (found in the root of the project directory) and add entries for key.store and key.alias. For example:

key.store=path/to/my.keystore
key.alias=mykeystore

ant release

It will prompt you to enter passphase for keystore and alias