# uploaded APK is signed with different certificate to your previous APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I got the updated code and apk from the app developer. I have rebuild the app with my own keystore files and signed the app and uploaded to the store
and received "uploaded APK is signed with different certificate to your previous APK".

I checked the updated apk sha1 files by

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs updated_apk.apk
```

and the sha1 files showing that are of the developer and the apk is not signed with my keystore files.

How to sign the updated app with my own keystore files?

Answer (score 1):

You either get the keystore file from the developer and sign with that or you have to re-name the packages of your app and re-upload it with your own keystore. But be aware that this might give you a strike for your developer account since it's basically a copy cat of a previous apk.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for an unsigned build.

There was a way to remove the signature and resign the application ([Can I re-sign an .apk with a different certificate than what it came with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267216/can-i-re-sign-an-apk-with-a-different-certificate-than-what-it-came-with)) but that is not working if the developer used the new v2 signing method...

The best would be to ask for an unsigned build. I assume the dev sent it to you signed so you can test the app.

Comment: This isn't correct. You can re-sign an APK and this will replace the previous signature.